# Is the Set of Closed Subsets containing some point $x$ measurable?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I have the space $[0,1]^2$ with the topology induced Euclidean distance metric.

I think I can define a probability space by a triple $(\mu, \Gamma([0,1]^2), \mathcal{B})$, where $\mu$ is a measure, $\Gamma([0,1]^2)$ is the space of closed subsets of $[0,1]^2$ equipped with the Hausdorff topology, $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Denote an element of $\Gamma(M)$ by $\mathcal{M}$.

Take point $x \in M$ (e.g the ordered pair $(.4, .9)$). Define a subset $\Gamma_x \subseteq \Gamma([0,1]^2)$:

$$\Gamma_x := \{ \mathcal{M} \in \Gamma([0,1]^2) | x \in \mathcal{M}\}$$

**My question: Is $\Gamma_x$ measurable?**

A way to think of the problem: I have a bunch of menus of points in $[0,1]^2$, and I will eventually choose from one of the menus. I have some beliefs about which menu I will face, and I want to know the chance that some ordered pair will be contained in the menu that I face. I want to define it as $\mu(\Gamma_x)$, but it's not immediately obvious that this is defined.

---

Some initial thoughts:

-It is not definitionally clear that $\Gamma_x$ is a countable union of sets in $\Gamma([0,1]^2)$.

-But perhaps I can view $\Gamma_x$ (or its complement) as an open cover, and then take a finite subcover? I think this would work if $\Gamma(M)$ is compact. Is $\Gamma(M)$ compact if $M$ is? I think it must be, as $[0,1]^2$ with the Euclidean metric is almost maximally well-behaved. If so, does anyone have a reference for this? Or should I use some other topology, following, e.g. Wattenberg (1977) or some other reference?

Comment: How do you define the measure $\mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Gamma_x$ is closed in $\Gamma([0,1]^2)$ equipped with the Hausdorff metric. Indeed, if $K$ is in $\Gamma([0,1]^2) \setminus \Gamma_x $, then $K$ must be disjoint from the disk $B(x,\epsilon)$ of radius $\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$, since $K$ is closed.
Therefore every set $ F \in \Gamma_x$ will have Hausdorff distance at least
$\epsilon$ from $K$, so the $\epsilon$ ball centered at $K$ will be disjoint from $\Gamma_x$.